# How does my Back Squat velocity profile relate to the traditional velocity zones?

Tags: speed, power, velocity

I am trying to figure out how I can make my Back Squat velocity profile more actionable, and how it relates to the traditional Velocity Zone found on the internet.

I see that my max power occurs at 142lbs (43% of my 1RM; velocity of 1.5m/s; max power at 1443W).

[image: My Back Squat Velocity Profile]

However, when I map my Back Squat velocity profile onto the traditional Velocity Zones image I get very confused cause the velocity and %'s definitely don't point to the same zones. My 1RM % states that I'm working on Speed/Strength but my velocity states that I'm working on starting strength.

How do I know which phase I'm working on the velocity profile?

[image: My velocity profile mapped on to traditional Velocity image]

Comment: I'll have to look into this more later but I'd suspect it's likely inaccurate below that 1.3 m/s threshold. How recent of a 1RM is 330 lb for you?

Comment: This week and I have 5 workouts in this profile